# How to open cygwin from python script, execute commands and take data from command line in file

Tags: python, cygwin, ctags

I am trying to open a subprocess so that i can open cygwin.bat file from a python script. I need to extract data from ctag parser. To extract this data I am using following command :

```
 ctags --c-kinds=vf --fields=+SKz -f - Name_of_file
```

It gives me variables and functions from the file on command line. 
This data I have to put in a file using python script. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you just want to execute system command and read its output. Am I right?

If so, you can do

```
os.popen(r'ctags --c-kinds=vf --fields=+SKz -f - Name_of_file').read()
```

or even directly redirect output stream to file by appending `> output.txt` to your command.

If your problem is to setup cygwin environment and execute script, this problem is not related to Python. In this case you can try to create you bat file or use `&&` operator in your command to setup environment first:

```
os.popen(r'cygwin.bat && ctags --c-kinds=vf --fields=+SKz -f - Name_of_file').read()
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I am able to open batch file but it does not process the command. so that i can get data from ctags

Comment: @AabhaGeed, what commands you run before you run command written in question? In general, you should be able to run one command (possibly complex one) from command line with no prior environment setup. In other word, if cygwin require some environment variables, they should be set in same command. Also, ensure that your command works and output to stdout. After you make your command to work in one line, you can read its stdout in Python. Anyway, please, provide all commands you run and their output.

Comment: I am able to open cygwin window using open as well as with         p = subprocess.Popen(filepath , shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE) After doing so If i execute the command :  ctags --c-kinds=vf --fields=+SKz -f - _02_Platform/Source/Target/*.h
 i get desired output on the screen

Comment: @AabhaGeed, find out how to run your command from cmd, not cygwin window. Hope, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673278/cygwin-run-script-silenty-from-run-command . I guess your command should be `c:\cygwin\bin\run.exe ctags --c-kinds=vf --fields=+SKz -f - Name_of_file` .

Comment: ctags is a parser for files. this parser is of gcc. I have to get data from the parser. so from the windows environment i open cygwin somewhow. trigger the parser. get required data for processing. Now.. i want to achieve this automatically from windows environment. so i need to trigger cygwin execute command, generate data in cygwin and process this data in windows environment

Comment: @AabhaGeed, let's be slightly abstract. You want to tun cygwin command and process its output in Python. Does it matter what ctags do? It is important is that ctags output data you want to capture. Cygwin commands are run from Windows console (not from cygwin window) using `c:\cygwin\bin\run.exe <your_command>`.  In python, `os.popen('c:\cygwin\bin\run.exe ctags --c-kinds=vf --fields=+SKz -f - Name_of_file').read()` returns string with ctags output.

Comment: by Either of the ways, I am able to open cygwin. But I am not able to execute the command. Can you please help?

Comment: @AabhaGeed, please, for each try you have done, include in your question code you execute and errors you get.

Comment: I could get through! Thanks for your help !

Comment: @AabhaGeed, congratulations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to switch in environments, write the command in os.popen or os.system or subprocess.Popen. Open cygwin -> Python Python_File.py to execute the script. This should do.