# subprocess.call using cygwin instead of cmd on Windows

Tags: python, windows, cmd, cygwin, subprocess

I'm programming on Windows 7 and in one of my Python projects I need to call [bedtools](http://bedtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), which only works with Cygwin on Windows. I'm new to Cygwin, installed the default version + everything needed for bedtools and then used Cygwin to install bedtools by using make as described in the [installation instructions](http://bedtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/installation.html).

```
$ tar -zxvf BEDTools.tar.gz
$ cd BEDTools-<version>
$ make
```

When I use the Cygwin terminal to call it manually like below, it works without problem and the output file contains the correct result.

```
bedtools_exe_path intersect -a gene_bed_file -b snp_bed_file -wa -wb > output_file
```

But when I use `subprocess.call` in my program it seems to use Windows cmd instead of Cygwin, which doesn't work.

```
arguments = [bedtools_exe_path, 'intersect', '-a', gene_bed_file, '-b',
             snp_bed_file, '-wa', '-wb', '>', output_file]
return_code = suprocess.call(arguments)
```

Results in no output file and a return code of `3221225781`.

---

```
arguments = [bedtools_exe_path, 'intersect', '-a', gene_bed_file, '-b',
             snp_bed_file, '-wa', '-wb', '>', output_file]
return_code = suprocess.call(arguments, shell=True)
```

Results in an empty output file and a return code of `3221225781`.

---

```
cygwin_bash_path = 'D:/Cygwin/bin/bash.exe'
arguments = [cygwin_bash_path, bedtools_exe_path, 'intersect', '-a', gene_bed_file, '-b',
             snp_bed_file, '-wa', '-wb', '>', output_file]
return_code = suprocess.call(arguments)
```

Results in no output file, a return code of `126` and

```
D:/BEDTools/bin/bedtools.exe: D:/BEDTools/bin/bedtools.exe: cannot execute binary file
```

---

```
arguments = [cygwin_bash_path, bedtools_exe_path, 'intersect', '-a', gene_bed_file, '-b',
             snp_bed_file, '-wa', '-wb', '>', output_file]
return_code = suprocess.call(arguments, shell=True)
```

Results in an empty output file, a return code of `126` and

```
D:/BEDTools/bin/bedtools.exe: D:/BEDTools/bin/bedtools.exe: cannot execute binary file
```

---

Any ideas how I can get it to work?

Comment: try http://pastebin.com/Q4DZcpA7.  You cannot use `'>'` with shell=False. 126 means a permission problem or the file is not executable

Comment: If you want stderr redirected to the file also use `check_call(arguments,stdout=f,stderr=sunprocess.STDOUT)`

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment, unfortunately it produces the same result as the last example (empty output file, return code 126, bedtools.exe: cannot execute binary file). Why can't I use `'>'`?

Edit: When adding `stderr=subprocess:STDOUT` the output file is not empty but contains only the _bedtools.exe: cannot execute binary file_ line.

Comment: Are you running this from cygwin? Your output file is empty because the code errors so the output is through stderr not stdout

Comment: I run the code in PyCharm.

Comment: Also using shell=True you would pass a single string of args string

Comment: Using `check_call([cygwin_bash_path,"ls"])` writes _/usr/bin/bash: ls: No such file or directory_ into the output file.

Comment: That produces an empty output file, return code 127 and _/usr/bin/bash: ls: No such file or directory_

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That happens with and without shell=True, with and without passing arguments as a string or as a list.

Comment: @eryksun Not invoking bash is what I tried first and it doesn't work because then it's Windows cmd which doesn't work with bedtools. When I try your example I get the same result as in my first example, only that I get an empty output file.

Comment: That results in `/cygdrive/d/BEDTools/bin/bedtools.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Comment: When I use the path to mintty.exe of cygwin, instead of the path to the bash.exe, the cygwin console opens with the path to my project folder but does not execute bedtools.

Comment: I added D:\Cygwin\bin to the system PATH environment when I installed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works without a problem. The `"` does not need to be escaped.

```
argument = 'sh -c \"' + bedtools_exe_path + ' intersect -a ' + gene_bed_file + 
           ' -b ' + snp_bed_file + ' -wa -wb\"'

with open(output_file, 'w') as file:
    subprocess.call(argument, stdout=file)
```

Using the following works as well:

```
argument = 'bash -c \"' + bedtools_exe_path + ' intersect -a ' + gene_bed_file + 
           ' -b ' + snp_bed_file + ' -wa -wb\"'

with open(output_file, 'w') as file:
    subprocess.call(argument, stdout=file)
```

With:

```
bedtools_exe_path = 'D:/BEDTools/bin/bedtools.exe'
gene_bed_file = 'output/gene.csv'
snp_bed_file = 'output/snps.csv'
output_file = 'output/intersect_gene_snp.bed'
```

Using the path to the cygwin bash.exe (`D:/Cygwin/bin/bash.exe`) instead of `bash` or `sh` does not work.

Thank you, eryksun, Padraic Cunningham and J.F. Sebastian.

Comment: you could write: `'sh -c "{} intersect -a {} -b {} -wa -wb"'.format(*map(pipes.quote, [bedtools_exe_path, gene_bed_file, snp_bed_file]))` to support POSIX paths with spaces (or other `sh`'s metacharacters).

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you want to run a Linux command from Windows. You could install Linux into a VM and run commands via ssh (Putty/plink on Windows):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

cmd = [r'C:\path\to\plink.exe', '-ssh', 'user@vm_host', '/path/to/bedtools']
with open('output', 'wb', 0) as file:
    subprocess.check_call(cmd, stdout=file)
```

Cygwin provides `run` command that allows to run commands directly:

```
cmd = [r'C:\cygwin\path\to\run.exe', '-p', '/path/to/', 'bedtools', 
        '-wait', 'arg1', 'arg2']
```

Note: Python script is run from Windows in both cases. `bedtools` is Linux or Cygwin (non-Windows) command here and therefore you should provide POSIX paths.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I used the 2nd one in several variations but it still does not work. `cmd = [cygwin_run_path, bedtools_exe_path, 'intersect', '-a', gene_bed_file, '-b', 'snp_bed_file', '-wa', '-wb']` results in return_code 0 and I can see the console flash for a millisecond, but the output file is still empty, everything else results in return code 1. If possible I'd prefer not to install a VM.

Comment: @eryksun passing it as a list or as a string gives the same results, I try every suggestion both ways. Since I use the same path formats I used in the cygwin terminal and it worked there, the paths shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @eryksun: `man run`. You could use [this question as a reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/673278/4279)

Comment: @MarkusH: could you run anything else e.g., `echo hello world` instead of `bedtools` and see whether the file has `hello world` in it

Comment: As I said, I tried several variations, the `-wait` did not work. Using the cygwin terminal for `echo hello world` works, using run to do the same via the windows console produces an empty file and other commands do not work that way either. Neither does it work in my program.

Comment: @MarkusH: if there is no `echo.exe` then run `sh -c "echo hello world"`

Comment: Thank you. `args = 'sh -c \"' + bedtools_path + ' intersect -a ' + gene_bed_file + ' -b ' + snp_bed_file + ' -wa -wb\"'` did the trick when using `args` for `subprocess.check_call(args, stdout=output_file)`

Comment: @eryksun it works with `sh`  and `bash`. I use paths in the following format `D:/BEDTools/bin/` that work both in Windows cmd and cygwin, cygwin does change them to `/cygdrive/d/BEDTools/bin/` though. It also works with and without escaping `"`.

Comment: @eryksun: there is no escaping: `len('\"') == 1` i.e.,    `'\"' == '"'` in Python

Comment: For this to work for me I had to run my script with a Run as Administrator windows shortcut.