# How to run bash script in the current directory from cmd-file by using Cygwin?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cygwin, working-directory

How to run bash script in the current directory from cmd-file by using Cygwin?

It doesn't work - my file `script.cmd` contains: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17204645/1558037

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\bash -l -c '%CD%/my_script.sh'
```

Output

```
E:\mydir>c:\cygwin64\bin\bash -l -c 'E:\mydir/my_script.sh'
/usr/bin/bash: E:mydir/my_script.sh: No such file or directory
```

**Answer:**

I can successfully use such commands:

- `c:\cygwin64\bin\bash -l -c "cd %CD:\=/%/; %CD:\=/%/my_script.sh"`
- `c:\cygwin64\bin\bash -l -c "cd %CD:\=/%/; echo $PWD"`

Comment: Please do not add answers to your question; if you want to share your solution just post it as an answer; thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the returned error message you showed the backslash between `E:` and `mydir` disappeared, which lets me assume `bash` uses such as escape characters.

Windows Command Prompt (`cmd`)  however uses backslashes as path separators, hence `%CD%` contains such. However, `bash` expects forward-slashes as path separators.

Therefore, to replace all backslashes by forward-slashes, use [sub-string substitution](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html), like this:

```cmd
c:\cygwin64\bin\bash -l -c '%CD:\=/%/my_script.sh'
```

In case the single-quotes cause troubles as well, use double-quotes:

```cmd
c:\cygwin64\bin\bash -l -c "%CD:\=/%/my_script.sh"
```

Comment: I don't know if the single-quotes could also be a problem, because `cmd` uses only double-quotes, so maybe they might need to be changed too, but I can't test, sorry...

Answer (score 2):

solution in two steps, first convert the %CD% with `cygpath`
then call `bash` with the converted path in POSIX format

```
FOR /F %%I IN ('c:\cygwin64\bin\cygpath -c -u %CD%') DO SET CDU=%%I
c:\cygwin64\bin\bash -l -c %CDU%/my_script.sh
```